# how to match a file extension name in a file

Tags: files, search, extension

i want to move a file into a directory, example i have file name extlist, its contains

```
.exe
.lnk
.inf
```

i try to use script like this

```
    #!/bin/sh
    a=`cat /home/harits/extlist`

    for f in $(find -type f -name "*.$a")
    do
    if [[ (this is difficult part) == $f]]
    then mv $f
    else
    echo "fail"
    fi
    done
```

and i want to move that file while it have same extension in extlist, should i use bash manipulation string?

sorry for my creepy english.., please guide me here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like I would use `egrep` for this, but you will have to change the format of your `extlist` file to use pipe characters ("|") instead of line breaks.

```
for f in $(find . -type f | egrep -i '\.(exe|lnk|inf)$')
do
    mv $f destination
done
```

Comment: so the extlist file its not useful?

Comment: i want this script work with check the extension file in every directory and match the extension in a file named extlist, if there is have a same extension, this script will move the file into a directory